# Conditionals within tikz node specification

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to specify custom hierarchies of tikz nodes where I do a few geometry calculations related to text depth, text width, text height, and so on.

In the process of writing custom commands to automate some of these calculations, I end up wanting to use TeX conditionals mixed in with tikz code. I read in another question that \pgfextra{} can be used for this. However, it seems that this only works at the level of the tikzpicture environment.

A minimal example of what I would like to do is the following:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal, border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifDebug
%\Debugtrue
\Debugfalse

\newcommand\MyNode{
  \node[anchor=north west,
        minimum width=5cm,
        minimum height=5cm,
        fill=green,
        \pgfextra{\ifDebug opacity=0.2,\fi}
        ] at (current page.north west) {}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \MyNode{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line containing \pgfextra is giving me trouble. What should I do to conditionally change arguments to \node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please try to avoid all `pgfextra` stuff. You can achieve almost everything with pgfkeys, also here.

```
\documentclass[class=minimal, border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifDebug
%\Debugtrue
\Debugfalse

\tikzset{Debug/.code={\ifDebug\pgfkeysalso{opacity=0.2}\fi}}

\newcommand\MyNode{
  \node[anchor=north west,
        minimum width=5cm,
        minimum height=5cm,
        fill=green,
        Debug,
        ] at (current page.north west) {}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Debugtrue
  \MyNode{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out `\Debugtrue`, I get.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With a Ti*k*z style (implemented with the `/.code` handler) this is rather straightforward:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal, border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifDebug
\Debugtrue
%\Debugfalse

\tikzset{
    my node/.code={
        \tikzset{
            anchor=north west,
            minimum width=5cm,
            minimum height=5cm,
            fill=green,
        }
        \ifDebug
           \tikzset{opacity=0.2}
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[my node]{};
  \Debugfalse
  \node[my node] at (6,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned by marmot in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450239/74459) you should stay away from `\pgfextra` in general. My personal preference is also to stay away from custom commands where `style`s can do the same, but that really is personal.

Comment: You were faster, +1. I don't know why someone would upvote only my answer, but not yours. Sad.

Comment: @marmot Well if someone thinks your solution is cleaner (which I could agree with) then it's a normal reaction :)